# Plotly Choropleth_mapbox not painting area

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I am trying to plot unemployment rate of Uruguay with fictitious values in plotly Choropleth_mapbox. My dataframe is called [uruguay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1xDO.png). The problem is that when I try to show the values of each department (province, is the same) is not showing nothing, I mean, is not painting the area. My code is the following:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.election()
geojson = px.data.election_geojson()

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(uruguay, geojson=geojson, color="Unemp_rate",
                        locations="Depto", featureidkey="properties.Depto",
                        center={"lat": -33.38160714046037, "lon":  -56.5245340},
                        mapbox_style="carto-positron", zoom=5.5)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[uruguay unemployment rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFtF5.png)

I tried to adapt my dataframe to the one publish in plotly for Montreal, Canada, via this link: https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/
The code of this case looks like this:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.election()
geojson = px.data.election_geojson()

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=geojson, color="Bergeron",
                           locations="district", featureidkey="properties.district",
                           center={"lat": 45.5517, "lon": -73.7073},
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron", zoom=9)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[Montreal elections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YUB9.jpg)

I really appreciate your help. Kind regards

Comment: To paint on the map, you need the geojson file for Uruguay. We will tie the user data provided in the image to it. So, using the data provided in the reference does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the geojson file for [Uruguay](https://cartographyvectors.com/map/1531-uruguay-with-regions) from here and created a map map with sample data similar to the data in your question. The reason it doesn't show up is that the geosjon associated region names are set by name division, so the featureidkey is the name of the geojson property, not the user data side. geojson file should be replaced with your geojson file. At that time, please check which field is set to the name of the region.

```
import numpy as np
import json

with open('./data/uruguay-with-regions_.geojson', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

region_names = []
for i in range(len(geojson['features'])):
    rname = geojson['features'][i]['properties']['name']
    region_names.append(rname)

uruguay = pd.DataFrame({'Depto': region_names,
                   'Unemp_rate': np.random.uniform(0.0,15.0, len(region_names)),
                   'Country': ['Country']*len(region_names)
                  })

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(uruguay,
                           geojson=geojson,
                           color="Unemp_rate",
                           locations="Depto",
                           featureidkey="properties.name",
                           center={"lat": -33.38160714046037, "lon": -56.5245340},
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=5
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Now is saying me No such file or directory. I know is because of the geoson file of that web. How can I copy correctly? I mean with the URL or like you put it ('./data/uruguay-with-regions_.geojson') is not reading it correctly.

Comment: On the website mentioned in the answer, in the red box at the top right side, there is a drop-down for map format, click on it and you will see geojson, click on it and download it. Place the downloaded geojson file in a location where it can be read by the script.